# SnappyCompressionCodec on the master

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running spark standalone cluster (1.4.0). I have some applications running with scheduler every hour. I found that on one of the executions, the job got to be FINISHED after very few seconds (instead of ~5 minutes), and in the logs on the master, I can see the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 20, 172.31.6.203): java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1257)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1254)
... 11 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
... 20 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

This job was successful many times before and after this run, and other jobs were successful in that time

Any idea what can cause that?

thanks, nizan

Comment: I've recently seen the same exception when running seemingly simple commands in the spark-shell

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the root cause for the problem was that the slaves ran out out of space, because of logs of the applications.

I passed the logs to a mounted dir, and removed the old logs, with the following command:

```
for slave in `cat /root/spark/conf/slaves`; 
  do echo $slave;
  ssh -A -t -i ~/.ssh/myKey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$slave "rm -rf  /home/hadoop/spark-logs/; mkdir /home/hadoop/spark-logs;  ln -s /mnt/spark-logs/ /home/hadoop/spark-logs/"
done
```

thanks, nizan